# Ftitting Lorentzians to Data. object of type 'numpy.uint16' has no len() error

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares

Below is some (messy) code that will hopefully fit lorentzians to data

```
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from scipy import optimize
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as ply
from scipy.optimize import leastsq


img_arr = scipy.misc.imread('water_1_0.tiff')
img=mpimg.imread('water_1_0.tiff')

img_arr_col_sum = img_arr.sum(axis=0)
maxI_col = img_arr_col_sum.argmax()
maxI_along = img_arr[:, maxI_col]
maxI_alongL = img_arr[:, maxI_col - 1]
maxI_row = maxI_along.argmax()

IntsR = img_arr[:, maxI_col+1].sum()
IntsL = img_arr[:, maxI_col-1].sum()
IntsMax = img_arr[:, maxI_col].sum()

Ray = [154, 284, 412]
ctr_list = Ray
amp_list = [790, 3864, 1030]
wid_list = [2,2,2]

p0 = [[ctr_list[i], amp_list[i], wid_list[i]] for i in range(3)]

pix = np.array(range(0,len(img_arr[:,maxI_col - 1])))  #Pixel position up to     500
I = img_arr[:,maxI_col - 1]                     #Intensities at each pixel posn

def lorentzian(x, params):
    L = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(len(params)):
        p0_nest = params[i]
        #print("nest", p0_nest)
        ctr = p0_nest[0]
        amp = p0_nest[1]
        wid = p0_nest[2]
        L = L + (amp*wid) / (2*np.pi*((x-ctr)**2+(0.5*wid)**2))
    return L

def residual(x, y, params):
    return lorentzian(x, params) - y

def fit(params):
    p = []
    global pix, I, Ray
    for i in range(len(Ray)):
        R_index = Ray[i]
        print(params[i])
        fit_range = slice(R_index -10, R_index + 10)
        params_opt, success = leastsq(residual, params[i], args = (pix[fit_range],I[R_index]))
        p.append(params_opt)
    return p
```

lorentzian(pix, p0)
residual(pix, I, p0)
fit(p0)``

When I call lorentzian and residual, all is fine. But when I call fit, I get the following error, which is driving me mad

```
 58 def lorentzian(x, params):
 59     L = np.zeros_like(x)
 60     for i in range(len(params)):   #This is where it goes wrong
 61         p0_nest = params[i]
 62         #print("nest", p0_nest)

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.uint16' has no len()
```

I'd appreciate any insights.

Thanks.

**EDIT: Problem resolved**

Comment: You are giving information that contradicts where you think the error is.  If lorentzian works without error, but calling fit throws an error, what makes you think the problem is on line 60 of lorentzian?  If you could provide the exact input to lorentzian that is causing issues it would be easier to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The lorentzian inputs are: pix = array from 0 to 500, and p0 = [[154, 790, 2], [284, 3864, 2], [412, 1030, 2]]. When fit is called, it manages to print upto [154, 790, 2], and then the error message flags.

Comment: When I run fit, I get a series of errors, the last of which being what's mentioned above. And yes, I agree, it seems totally contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems, one is probably just a transcription error.  Your code references `maxI_row = maxI_along.argmax()` , but what you actually defined is `maxI_alongL`, not `maxI_along`.

The main issue though, is that within lorentzian, on what would be line 63 of the snippet you included, you are trying to get the position of an integer.

For example, you passed in a list of 0..500 as params, you pull out on each iteration a particular number, store it in p0_nest, and then you try to get the index of that *integer* on the next line `ctr = p0_nest[0]`, which fails because integers don't have indices.

**Revision based on comments:**

Let's be conrete about the input:

```
x = np.array(range(0,501))
params = [[154, 790, 2], [284, 3864, 2], [412, 1030, 2]]
lorentzian(x,params)
```

This runs without error for me.  When you say x is an array, are you certain it is an np array?

Comment: Hi. I will check the thing about a possible transciption error. But on the second point, p0 is a list with three nested lists, so using the two indices shouldn't really be a problem - were this the problem, lorentzian and residue wouldn't work. But, I did notice that the block of code in question prints an integer (and it seems out of nowhere), which is causing the problem. I just can't find it.

Comment: that is not what you had for the inputs originally, you edited the comment since i last looked.  Let me take another look.

Comment: x runs from 0 to 499. In the code, I call x "pix" (for pixels), and, yes, it's an np array. The params look good to me.

Comment: given those parameters, i cannot reproduce your issue so not sure I can help.  The only things I changed were, as mentioned, the definition of `maxI_row` to reference maxI_alongL instead of `maxI_along` (which was undefined).  Other than that, since i dont have either of the `tiff` files, I just assumed what you said for the `x` parameter is accurate (that it is a np.array from 0 to 499).  My guess is that this is where your problem is.

Comment: Hi. I have edited the code so it matches more closely what I was working with (it had loads of junk lying around). For the data, copy the following url                                                                                                               (file:///C:/Users/OMAR/Downloads/water_1%20(2)/)  Choose File: water_1_1.tiff           Thanks

Comment: nor sure how you expect me to download files off your personal drive...

Answer (score 0):

The call signature for your objective function looks to be not correct. The fitting code inside `leastsq` will call your objective function `residual()` with the updated parameter values as an ndarray (float64) in the ***first argument***.  Any additional arguments you may want to use to calculate the residual to be minimized (such as data values or your ordinate values `x`) come *after* the parameters.  In a sense, `leastsq` doesn't really care about your arrays `x` and `y`, it is concerned with how your objective function responds to the parameter values.

For fitting data to Lorentzian functions, you may find the `lmfit` module useful. For an example, see https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-1-fit-peaked-data-to-gaussian-lorentzian-and-voigt-profiles